# Angular 2 to MVC call - Javascript doesn't execute

Tags: javascript, angular2-template

I have defined templateUrl in the @Component of a typescript file. this url is pointing to a MVC view.

Parent page is like link1 link2 link3.

link2 has a typescript file linked to it as above along with the templateUrl.

When i click link2 it loads the MVC view but the javascript within the test.cshtml doesn't execute. please can you let know where am i missing ?

Parent HTML

```
<h1>Angular 2 App</h1>

<div>
    <a routerLink="/contacts/list">Contacts</a>
    <a routerLink="Dashboard">Dashboard</a>
    <a href="Settings">Settings</a>

</div>

<hr />

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Dashboard.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    templateUrl: '/Test/Test',
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

}
```

Test.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
@using Angular2RoutesWithMvc.Models

@{
    var prod = (Test)ViewData["testm"];
}

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body onload="fetch();">

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function fetch() {
            document.getElementById('test').textContent = 'Call from JS';
        }

    </script>

    <div>
        <h1>Details</h1>
        <h3>Name: @prod._name</h3>
        <h3>Surname: @prod._surname </h3>
        <h3>Age: @prod._age</h3>
        <label id="test">test1</label>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: why are you mixing angular and js

Comment: you seem to only be declaring the function, but not invoking it.

Comment: @Rahul we have MVC views developed and need to use this existing view in angular. to save time and re-work we are looking to call MVC view in angular.

@ Temi i have tried calling explicitly on onload function now, but no luck.

Comment: @chint i get it but i dnt think so it is possible , why would some one mix server and client side things